# Auto-register all interfaces with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Using Unity, I'd like to automatically register all interface/class combinations in an assembly based on the following convention:

```
INameOfObject > NameOfObject
```

StructureMap does that when the default conventions are enabled.

I wrote the following method for it:

```
private static IUnityContainer RegisterITypesOf(this IUnityContainer container, string assemblyName)
{
  Assembly.Load(assemblyName)
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name))
    .ForEach(t => container.RegisterType(t.GetInterface("I" + t.Name, false), t));
  return container;
}
```

My question is:

- is there a built-in function that does the same?
- if not, can my code be improved performance wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted the same as you; convention based configuration ala Structuremap, and went ahead and created a library for it. You can download it on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/UnityConfiguration), and read some documentation on my [github page](https://github.com/thedersen/UnityConfiguration)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice lib! It pretty much does it the same way, so I'm going to assume that it's the best way of doing it :)

Answer (score 17):

Unity 3.5.140.0 has built in functionality to register interfaces with similar names as the class that uses it.

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default);
}
```

Comment: Cool, good to know. Blogpost with explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/03/12/unity-configuration-registration-by-convention.aspx

Comment: Therefore you should include the namespace `Unity.RegistrationByConvention`.

Comment: @David the link you posted is dead.

Comment: @aallalajr I used the example above, but get an object reference issue. However, when I assign the object this way "`container.RegisterType<IAnalyticsSevice, AnalyticsService>();`" it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unity does not have support for conventions. But the [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com) contains an [enhanced configuration engine for Unity](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AdvancedConfigurationEngineForUnity&referringTitle=Documentation) that is based on StructureMap's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can register by convention...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507479(v=pandp.30).aspx